# Problems with proven complexity but no algorithm yet found

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Does there exists a computable problem P such that:

- Is proven that P can be solved with an algorithm that has a certain complexity.
- The best algorithm know unluckily is still slower (greater complexity) than the proven bound.

**Example:**

- A problem that we have proven can be solved in worst case in $O(n^2)$ operations.
- The best algorithm that's currently known runs in $\Omega(n^3)$ time.

Comment: Where have you looked? A [simple Google query](https://encrypted.google.com/#hl=en&q=complexity%20non%2Dconstructive%20proof) leads to promising results, in particular [on cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/12162/1546) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-constructive_algorithm_existence_proofs).

Comment: @Raphael I put no constraints on it being constructive or not, but if one is already answered I'm interested in the other

Comment: Yes, you are asking for problems with non-constructive complexity proofs; a constructive proof would give you an algorithm as witness.